# Regex without symbols

Tags: regex, lex

I have this regex:

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9"_/.!\*\+\<\>\{\}$#\[\]]*
```

This is used to match words separated by space like these:

```
 eyes
 yellow
 9+3
 goin$crazy
 mou{s}e
```

Unfortunately it matches also this kind of string:

```
 a${try}b
```

I desire to match the same words but avoiding all words containing the sequence "${". How can I do it?

**EDIT**

It is really important to do it in a single regex due to the fact I need this regex to be used to define a flex token.

Here is the flex code:

```
%option noyywrap
%option prefix="exp"
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "expr.tab.h"

char *p; 

extern int yywrap(void);
%}

NUM [0-9]+ 
STR <HERE HAVE TO BE INSERTED THE REGEX I NEED>
VAR $\{[-a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*\}

%%

=           { /*printf("EQ\n");*/ return EQ; }
\)          { /*printf("RPAREN\n");*/ return RPAREN; }
\(          { /*printf("LPAREN\n");*/ return LPAREN; }
\}          { /*printf("KET\n");*/ return KET; }
\{          { /*printf("BRA\n");*/ return BRA; }
"]"         { /*printf("RSBRA\n");*/return RSBRA; }
:           { /*printf("COLON\n");*/ return COLON; }
;           { /*printf("SEMICOLON\n");*/ return SEMICOLON; }
,           { /*printf("COMMA\n");*/ return COMMA; }
"=>"        { /*printf("ARROW\n");*/ return ARROW; }
\|          { /*printf("PIPE\n");*/return PIPE; }
@           { /*printf("AT\n");*/return AT; }
&           { /*printf("AND\n");*/return AND; }
"${"        { /*printf("VARBEGIN\n");*/return VARBEGIN;}
"$["        { /*printf("EXPRINIT\n");*/return EXPRINIT;}
"!="        { /*printf("NOTEQ\n");*/return NOTEQ; }
"=="        {/*printf("EQUAL\n");*/return EQUAL;}
">"         { /*printf("GT\n");*/return GT; }
"<"         { /*printf("LT\n");*/return LT; }
">="        { /*printf("GTEQ\n");*/return GTEQ; }
"<="        { /*printf("LTEQ\n");*/return LTEQ; }
"+"         { /*printf("PLUS\n");*/return PLUS; }
"-"         { /*printf("MINUS\n");*/return MINUS; }
"*"         { /*printf("MULT\n");*/return MULT; }
"/"         { /*printf("DIV\n");*/return DIV; }
"%"         { /*printf("MOD\n");*/return MOD; }
"!"         { /*printf("LOGNOT\n");*/return LOGNOT; }
"=~"        { /*printf("LIKEOP\n");*/return LIKEOP; }
"?"         { /*printf("CONDQUEST\n");*/return CONDQUEST; }

{NUM}   {
    /*printf("VARNAME (%s)\n",yytext);*/
    p = (char*)calloc(strlen(yytext)+1,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(p,yytext);
    yylval = (YYSTYPE)p;
    return NUM;
    }

{VAR}   {
    /*printf("VARNAME (%s)\n",yytext);*/
    p = (char*)calloc(strlen(yytext)+1,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(p,yytext);
    yylval = (YYSTYPE)p;
    return VAR;
    }

{STR}   {
    /*printf("VARNAME (%s)\n",yytext);*/
    p = (char*)calloc(strlen(yytext)+1,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(p,yytext);
    yylval = (YYSTYPE)p;
    return STR;
    }
%%
```

**EDIT 2**
I have created this rule and it seems to work, but is not perfect because it is not able to match string containing only character "$" or only character "{".

```
(\$[-a-zA-Z0-9"_/.!\*\+\<\>#$}\[\]]|\{[-a-zA-Z0-9"_/.!\*\+\<\>#\$\{}\[\]]|[-a-zA-Z0-9"_/.!\*\+\<\>#}\[\]])*
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your definition of word.

Comment: in this case is simply a sequence of character matched by the regex I have posted but I want to force it to not contain the sequence of characters "${"

Answer (score 1):

What if you place **VAR** before **STR**? Won't it catch first? (I don't know Flex, but it works in other languages).

Regardless, the full regex is in this form:

A = without $

B = without $ and without {

(A* | (A*$+BA*)*)$* leading to (A*($+B)?)*$* leading to **([B{]*($+B)?)*$***

Comment: VAR is already placed before string in rule definition. Flex consider the precedence of rules only if two tokens are able to match a string of the same length, otherwise it consider first the rule matching the longest string.

Regarding the rule you have posted, it seems that, with this rule, I can't match words like "$a{b}c$" that are valid strings

Comment: So I forgot to carry the 1 :). Just need to add $* at the end of the regex: ([B{]*($+B)?)*$*

Comment: The resulting regex would be `([-a-zA-Z0-9"_/.!\*\+\<\>#$}\[\]]*($+[-a-zA-Z0-9"_/.!\*\+\<\>#}\[\]])?)*$*` but it doesn't match anyone of the suggested examples.

Comment: Nope, you missed the { in [B{] and added a $. So the resulting should be: `([-a-zA-Z0-9"_/.!\*\+\<\>#{}\[\]]*($+[-a-zA-Z0-9"_/.!\*\+\<\>#}\[\]])?)*$*`

Comment: sorry but, also this doesn't match anything in my examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second regexp that specifically excludes the `${` sequence, and combine it with the `not` operator. While it is possible to do what you ask in one regexp, it is way more complicated and will become unreadable legacy code the second after you've written it.

Comment: I need this regex for a flex token, then it should be done a unique regex.

Comment: Okay, but you can't use character classes for that because they don't have any notion of context. You need either negative look-behind declarations or a big disjunction: something like "Either `{` when not preceded by `$` or any of the other permissible word characters" and apply the quantifier to the whole thing. If you don't even have look-behind you need two big character classes and apply the quantifier only to the second one - ugly! This is why I hate tools that force you to do stuff in  single regexp.

Comment: I sadly know this is ugly but I have not "look-behind not" operators in flex and than can you please post the regexp you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

The regex `[-a-zA-Z0-9"_/.!\*\+\<\>\{\}$#\[\]]*` matches a sequence of all symbols. What you wish is therefore a sequence of arbitrarily many of the following:

- **either** the `{` symbol
- **or** any symbol except `$` or `{`, preceded by any number of `$` symbols (including zero)

Followed by:

- any number of `$` symbols (including zero)

Resulting in this regex:

```
([\{]|[$]*[-a-zA-Z0-9"_/.!\*\+\<\>\}#\[\]])*[$]*
```

Some of the extra `[]`s are not necessary but I think they improve clarity.

Comment: trying this regexp, it seems to match also strings containing the sequence "${"

Comment: Oh, now I see how this is possible, but it actually matches the final `$`, not the following `{`. If you remove the trailing `[$]*` it will work better but you will miss all `$`s at the end of matching strings. You can't have a perfect amswer with simple regex, but I'll check what is the lex way of solving that.